# Unity not resolving repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the classes below:

**SuppliersRepository.cs** (with the interface defining the method):

```
    public class SuppliersRepository : BaseRepository,ISuppliersRepository
    {
        public IEnumerable<Supplier> GetSuppliersByCoordinates(double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            using (IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection())
            {
                const string query = "SELECT ID=SupplierID,Name=Suppliername FROM suppliers WHERE dbo.Distance(@latitude,@longitude,latitude,longitude) < 15 AND latitude IS NOT NULL AND longitude IS NOT NULL";
                return connection.Query<Supplier>(query, new { latitude = latitude,longitude=longitude });
            }
        }

    }
```

**BaseRepository.cs** (with the interface defining the method)

```
public abstract class BaseRepository: IBaseRepository
{
    public IDbConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        return connection;
    }
```

}

A **Bootstraper.cs** called from global.asax.cs with:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void Initialise()
        {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer();

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        }

        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();

            container.RegisterType<IBaseRepository, BaseRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<ISuppliersRepository, SuppliersRepository>();
            container.RegisterInstance<IHttpControllerActivator>(new HttpControllerActivator(container));
            container.RegisterControllers();


            return container;
        }
    }
```

And two controllers, first one resolves the repository fine:

```
public class VenueController : MasterController
    {
        [Dependency]
        public SuppliersRepository _SuppliersRepository { get; set; }
    }
```

But this one fails:

```
public class AjaxController : Controller
    {
        [Dependency]
        public BaseRepository _BaseRepository { get; set; }
}
```

It throws a **System.InvalidOperationException: The type BaseRepository cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.**

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's better to use constructor injection instead of property injection. This way you don't have to decorate your properties with the `[Dependency]` attribute, and prevents your application code to take a dependency on Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when using dependency injection, it's better to have dependencies on interfaces, rather than having dependencies on concrete classes. I would change your controllers to

```
public class VenueController : MasterController
{
    [Dependency]
    public ISuppliersRepository _SuppliersRepository { get; set; }
}


public class AjaxController : Controller
{
    [Dependency]
    public IBaseRepository _BaseRepository { get; set; }
}
```

Second, `BaseRepository` is `abstract` class. Instances of abstract class can not be constructed, and I think that's the reason why it fails when unity comes to actually creating `BaseRepository`. You should inject concrete classes.

```
container.RegisterType<IBaseRepository, SomeConcreteImplementationOfBaseRepository>();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was being lazy and I added the method in my BaseRepository and if cannot be constructed being abstract I then move the method to another class based on BaseRepository and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your classes to take a property of IRepository, e.g:

```
public class AjaxController : Controller
{
        [Dependency]
        public IRepository _BaseRepository { get; set; }
}
```

Your properties should always be defined in terms of the interface, not the concrete implementation, otherwise you have tied yourself to the implementation, thus making the use of dependency injection rather pointless!

Comment: Fair enough, I originally injected the interface but I changed this because it wasn't working and was running out of ideas!

Comment: @RB - Although you are right in that DI is usually used with interface segregation, OP could use Unity to inject a derived SuppliersRepository into any BaseRepository property, i.e. container.RegisterType<BaseRepository, SuppliersRepository>();